# Python plotly_Connection markers with labels within line

Tags: python, annotations, plotly, geo

In the code below I have marker labels.
Now I want to make lines which connect center of markers with text (see pic below).
[image]

What is the way to make it?

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd

rows=[['501-600','15','122.58333','45.36667'],
      ['till 500','4','12.5','27.5'],
      ['more 1001','41','-115.53333','38.08'],
      ]

colmns=['bins','data','longitude','latitude']
df=pd.DataFrame(data=rows, columns=colmns)
df = df.astype({"data": int})

fig=px.scatter_geo(df,lon='longitude', lat='latitude',
                      color='bins',
                      opacity=0.5,
                      size='data',
                      projection="natural earth")

fig.update_traces(hovertemplate ='bins')

fig.add_trace(go.Scattergeo(lon=df["longitude"],
              lat=df["latitude"],
              text=df["data"],
              textposition="middle right",
              mode='text',
              showlegend=False))
fig.show()
```

In case you added 10 to the longitude, there appered arcs reflecting parallels on the globe. It's very visible on big scale or whent you add bigger figures in code.
[image]

Comment: this is usually done with [annotations](https://plotly.com/python/text-and-annotations/#simple-annotation)

Comment: I know,  already tried it (see comment above the question), but I can't solve issue with coordinate system then (

Comment: [this](https://community.plotly.com/t/choropleth-map-with-annotations/24107/2) might help if it's going to be a static map.

Comment: I cannot think of a way to make the lines straight. Honestly, I think that's not a big deal. You usually won't zoom in that much (it defeats the purpose of a map which is seeing locations in relation to each other) and even if you do, whats the harm in little curve. It still shows that the label is for that point.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [`annotations` options](https://plotly.com/python/text-and-annotations/) I couldn't figure out how to use `update_layout` within the maps. What I think of was adding the labels at some distance (here, I added 10 to the longitude)  from the points and then adding the lines manually. See below;

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd

rows=[['501-600','15','122.58333','45.36667'],
      ['till 500','4','12.5','27.5'],
      ['more 1001','41','-115.53333','38.08'],
      ]

colmns=['bins','data','longitude','latitude']
df=pd.DataFrame(data=rows, columns=colmns)
df = df.astype({"data": int})
df = df.astype({"longitude": float})
df = df.astype({"latitude": float})

fig=px.scatter_geo(df,lon='longitude', lat='latitude',
                      color='bins',
                      opacity=0.5,
                      size='data',
                      projection="natural earth")

fig.update_traces(hovertemplate ='bins')


fig.add_trace(go.Scattergeo(lon=df["longitude"]+10,
              lat=df["latitude"],
              text=df["data"],
              textposition="middle right",
              mode='text',
              showlegend=False))

for i in range(len(df)):
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scattergeo(
            lon = [df['longitude'][i], df['longitude'][i]+9],
            lat = [df['latitude'][i], df['latitude'][i]],
            mode = 'lines',
            line = dict(width = 1,color = 'red'),
            showlegend=False
        )
    )


fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: That's cool idea, but these lines not looks like straight now, but arcs, coz it goes like meridian. Do you have an idea how to make these line segments straight?

Comment: @Dmitry I don't see them as curves. Please update your question and add an example of that.