# Plotly: How to customize labels in a scattergeo plot?

Tags: python, text, label, plotly, marker

In the code below I have marker labels which now is located close to these markers. What is the way to make customise destination between marker and it's label? I want to put labels a little bit far from markers now.

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd

rows=[['501-600','15','122.58333','45.36667'],
      ['till 500','4','12.5','27.5'],
      ['more 1001','41','-115.53333','38.08'],
      ]

colmns=['bins','data','longitude','latitude']
df=pd.DataFrame(data=rows, columns=colmns)
df = df.astype({"data": int})

fig=px.scatter_geo(df,lon='longitude', lat='latitude',
                      color='bins',
                      opacity=0.5,
                      size='data',
                      projection="natural earth")

fig.update_traces(hovertemplate ='bins')

fig.add_trace(go.Scattergeo(lon=df["longitude"],
              lat=df["latitude"],
              text=df["data"],
              textposition="middle right",
              mode='text',
              showlegend=False))
fig.show()
```

Comment: In what way is this question different to your other question [Python plotly_Annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61937245/python-plotly-annotations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you're using a second `Scattergeo` trace to display your labels. And this does not seem to be a bad idea since it seems to me that `fig.add_annotation` can be  bit tricky in a `px.scatter_geo` figure. So I would simply adjust the latitude and longitude numbers slightly to get the labels in the positions you prefer, like `lon=[float(d) + 10 for d in df['longitude']]`:

[image]

**Complete code:**

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd

rows=[['501-600','15','122.58333','45.36667'],
      ['till 500','4','12.5','27.5'],
      ['more 1001','41','-115.53333','38.08'],
      ]

colmns=['bins','data','longitude','latitude']
df=pd.DataFrame(data=rows, columns=colmns)
df = df.astype({"data": int})

fig=px.scatter_geo(df,lon='longitude', lat='latitude',
                      color='bins',
                      opacity=0.5,
                      size='data',
                      projection="natural earth")

fig.update_traces(hovertemplate ='bins')

fig.add_trace(go.Scattergeo(lon=[float(d) + 10 for d in df['longitude']],
                              lat=[float(d) - 10 for d in df['latitude']],
                              text=df["data"],
                              textposition="middle right",
                              mode='text',
                              showlegend=False))
fig.show()
```

Comment: That's great option, but maybe you know how to put into this condition not only absolute values. Coz labels on the different distances from different markers. I believe in this case here should be dependency between label coordinates and value in `data`.

Comment: @Dmitry I guess it should. I'll take a look when I find the time.